# ScrollView elements hide behind ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

When I tap on a text field and the keyboard pops up, the upper few fields of my ScrollView hide behind the ActionBar.

[image]

If you look at the scrollbar, that is at the very top. That means even if I scroll up now, the elements will not come into view.

I am using ActionBarSherlock. I am not sure if it is the problem with the ABS or with the ScrollView.

Here is the code of my scrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_MessageUpdate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MessengerActivity"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:background="@drawable/repeating_bg"
>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_MessageUpdate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/repeating_bg"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPostedBy"
            android:hint="@string/txtPostedByHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="12"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dip">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:hint="@string/txtPostTitleHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPostedBy"
            android:ems="12"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            android:inputType="text">
        </EditText>


        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:hint="@string/txtMessageHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="3"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPostTitle"
        />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/txtComment"
            android:hint="@string/txtCommentHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="5"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMessage"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUpdateMessage"
            android:text="@string/btnUpdateText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtComment"
            style="@style/styledBuutonNoIcon_text"
            android:background="@drawable/styled_inner_form_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCancelMessage"
            android:text="@string/btnCancelText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnUpdateMessage"
            style="@style/styledBuutonNoIcon_text"
            android:background="@drawable/styled_inner_form_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPostTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip" />

        <!-- 
        <Button
            android:text="@string/btnDeleteText"
            android:id="@+id/btnDeleteSchool"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnCancelSchool"
            style="@style/styledBuutonNoIcon_text"
            android:background="@drawable/styled_inner_form_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtSchoolWebsite"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtSchoolWebsite"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
            />
         -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode` of your activity in manifest.xml to `"adjustPan"`?

Comment: The "Messages" thing is definitely not an ActionBar. And your layout is not full. It seems line the ScrollView is below the "Messages" bar.

Comment: @AaronHe it's not exactly what I was looking for. But it seems it fixed my problem.

Comment: @AaronHe can you please post it as answer. So I can accept it?

Comment: @DoctororDrive you are right. I had to write tabs instead of ActionBar.

Comment: You can use the tabs of ActionBarSherlock, not instead of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `android:windowSoftInputMode` of your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `"adjustPan"`.

According to [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft):

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

Comment: In fact `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` did exactly what I was looking for. But I am accepting your answer as you put me to the right direction.

Comment: @AdilMalik Happy to hear you have solved your problem! Thank you, btw. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem by removing "center" in the main layout

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
```